# How to send Consumption Information to App Store to make refund successfully

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

As we know, the customer initiated a refund request for a consumable in-app purchase, the CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification will be received on the developer server side. The developer could [send consumption info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/send_consumption_information)(one new App Store Server API) to help the app store to do refund decisions.

Recently, some users of our apps ask us to do a refund, since they got the information that the developer refused to refund from app store. We think this `Send Consumption Information` could help us to make the refund have a greater chance of success. How could we send this consumption info? Or is there any misunderstanding of this API?

There are several cases we have tried, unfortunately, the app store refused to refund all.

case 1: The customer is an inactive user and our app failed to deliver IAP product to the customer and the customer did not consume this product, the content of ConsumptionRequest
is below.

```
AccountTenure:            1
AppAccountToken:          "",
ConsumptionStatus:        1, 
CustomerConsented:        true, 
DeliveryStatus:           5,
LifetimeDollarsPurchased: 2,
LifetimeDollarsRefunded:  1,
Platform:                 1,
PlayTime:                 0,
SampleContentProvided:    false,
UserStatus:               0,
```

case 2: The customer is an active user and our app failed to deliver IAP product to the customer and the customer did not consume this product, the content of ConsumptionRequest
is below.

```
AccountTenure:            1
AppAccountToken:          "",
ConsumptionStatus:        1,
CustomerConsented:        true,
DeliveryStatus:           5,
LifetimeDollarsPurchased: 2,
LifetimeDollarsRefunded:  1,
Platform:                 1,
PlayTime:                 4,
SampleContentProvided:    false,
UserStatus:               1
```

case 3: The customer is an active user and our app delivers IAP product to the customer successfully and the customer did not consume this product, the content of ConsumptionRequest is below.

```
AccountTenure:            1
AppAccountToken:          "",
ConsumptionStatus:        1,
CustomerConsented:        true,
DeliveryStatus:           0,
LifetimeDollarsPurchased: 2,
LifetimeDollarsRefunded:  1,
Platform:                 1,
PlayTime:                 4,
SampleContentProvided:    false,
UserStatus:               1
```

All the above cases were sent to app store through API successfully, status code 202 is returned. However, Apple still declined those refunds.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Did you try and send the consumption info and the server rejected the transaction or did you successfully send the consumption info and Apple still declined the refund or are you asking how to send the consumption info?

Comment: @Paulw11, Sorry for the unclear question. we successfully send the consumption info and Apple still declined the refund. I will update this question

Comment: There probably isn't much more you can do.  Apple has more information than just what you provide; has the user received refunds before, what was their method of payment, what other activity is there on their App Store account.

Comment: @Paulw11, If app store could make a refund decision itself, why did this API send consumption info is created? It seems this API is useless.

Comment: Read the "discussion" section https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/send_consumption_information - your server is helping them make a decision but there are other factors that affects their decision

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, we want to give some information to app store to make refund a big chance to succeed. However, we have no idea how to give information like that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236900/discussion-between-paulw11-and-zangw).

Comment: Just wanted to add that, after reading their document, we have to obtain permission fro the consumer and it's very strict criteria. We may land in other issues with appstore while submitting app update with these things on. It is just useless, the whole process is useless as Apple will do what they want to do with or without us submitting any information to them. It is also not clear what exactly to submit to Apple?

Comment: @Raymond, Yes, you are right. We tested this send consumption info api with real money payment, and different parameters test. Unfortunately, there is NO refund from Apple...

Comment: @zangw could you let us know what details did you send into this API? I seem to find not details regarding this on their documents.

Comment: @Raymond, the details I mentioned above are the [ConsumptionRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/consumptionrequest?changes=latest_minor). Sorry for that if some misleading information